# Difference between [][[]] and [[]][] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

The result of **[ ][[ ]]** is *undefined* 
where as this **[[ ]][ ]** throws *SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]*.
Any Explanation?

Comment: BTW, why do you need to define something like this?

Comment: Did you try it? What "[[]]" is? It's an array with one item (an empty array). Then [[]] [] will get the first element of it but you need to provide an INDEX (that's why the syntax error, it parses "]" instead of a number).

Comment: `([])[ 'array object somekey, ie [ ]' ]` gives undefined .. and `([[]])[]` means `no key ` throws `SyntaxError: syntax error`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `object[key]` syntax is used to get the property of the `object` by the `key`, which must have `key` inside `[]` otherwise there will be syntax error.

`[][[]]`, the object is an empty array `[]`, and the key is another empty array `[]`.

`[[]][]`, the object is an array with an empty array inside it, while there is no key inside `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` defines an empty array, so `[][[]]` could be rewritten as:

```
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = a[b];
```

Now accessing an array by index where the index itself is an array is undefined - the standard doesn't say what should happen, but it's syntactically valid.

However `[[]][]` is broken - the closest this can be written longhand is:

```
var a = [];
var b = [];
[b]a;
```

...which is nonsense code.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why anyone would **ever** want to use something like this, but here is an explanation:

**Case 1:**

`[]` is an empty array. By adding `[n]` to it (`[][n]`), you reference the n-th element. *n* in your case is `[]`. The interpreter tries to convert that to a usable value and ends up with an empty string (""). So you actually try to reference `[][""]` which is *undefined*.

**Case 2:**

`[[]]` is an empty array inside an empty array. By adding `[n]` to it (`[[]][n]`), you reference the n-th element of the outer array. You need to provide the index *n*, otherwise it throws an error, which happens in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why you would need to use this, but here is my explanation:

[[]] is new Array( new Array()), which is an array with ONE element, an empty array.

[] is an empty array, so you can do [][2], or [][0] and it returns undefined. The second [] is  the index.

So in  [] [[]] you are looking for an index, the index [].

```
[][0] == [][[]]
```

But in [[]] [] the index is empty, is equivalent to [1,2,3][] -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Answer (score 0):

ok. simply you should access array with a key. else it will throw syntax error.

`[][[]]` - array defined and you are accessing key `[]` from that array which is undefined.

`[[]][]` - array defined and you are not passing any key to access from that array - syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a type conversion occurs :

```
[][
    // an index is expected here
    [] // so javascript probably tries to get a number from this empty array
]
```

This might be equivalent to :

```
[][+[]] // +[] gives 0
```

While in this pattern `[[]][]` two arrays are declared side by side.

Comment: It actually tries to convert it into a string, ending up with [][""]. You can try this out. var arr = []; arr[""] = "test"; console.log(arr[[]]);

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript object has properties associated with it. You access the properties of an object with a simple dot-notation or bracket notation, and if `non existing key` refered it gives `undefined` value.

```
var obj = {};
obj[ 'key' ]
```

and one important thing is that in JavaScript array is a Object

```
console.log( [] instanceof Object ) // gives true so it act like object
```

and funny thing is that we pass like below .

```
var keyCanbeFunction = function(){};
var keyCanbeObject = {};
var keyCanbeArray = [] ;

console.log( obj[ keyCanbeArray ] ) // gives undefined, that key not exists
```

**and 1 st case** :

```
var obj = [];
obj[ keyCanbeArray  ] // gives undefined
```

**and 2nd case** :

```
var obj = [[ ]]
obj[]; // where is key ???
```